# How to unserialize a string to array

Tags: php, arrays

This may not be an appropriate question for stack overflow so I apologize in advance. I am following behind another persons code and I came across this odd array of values.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"25";i:1;s:2:"26";}
```

Seems like the `a` value states the number of items, then there is an `i` value and an `s` value. I have never seen this and not entirely sure how to approach it. Before I make something up I was just wondering if this is some kind of standard I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `serialized` string you should `unserialize` it using this function [**unserialize**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='a:2:{i:0;s:2:"25";i:1;s:2:"26";}';
print_r(unserialize($string));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 25
    [1] => 26
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: @sixstring welcome.... :)