# How can I parse serialized data with PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, serialization

This is an example of my serialized data:

```
a:10:{s:7:"contact";s:1:"1";s:19:"profile_affiliation";s:23:"University, Inc.";s:18:"profile_first_name";s:3:"Ben";s:22:"profile_street_address";s:19:"8718 Tot Ave. S.";s:12:"profile_city";s:6:"Mobile";s:13:"profile_state";s:2:"AL";s:15:"profile_country";s:3:"USA";s:15:"profile_zipcode";s:5:"36695";s:18:"profile_home_phone";s:10:"2599494420";s:17:"profile_last_name";s:6:"Powers";}
```

I want to be able to parse through it with PHP and display the values like so:

- profile_first_name: Ben
- profile_last_name: Powers
- profile_state: AL

I know I need to unserialize it like so:

```
$unserialize = unserialize($data);
```

but I'm having trouble parsing the array with PHP. I keep getting "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" errors and the incorrect array output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unserialize a string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703206/how-to-unserialize-a-string-to-array)

Comment: where is the foreach loop?

Comment: Dump `$unserialize` and check what it contains and show us your code

Comment: Have you manipulated that string manually? That's a big no-no when it comes to serialized PHP-strings. They get corrupted and can't be unserialized again, if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
    <?php

    $serialized = 'a:10:{s:7:"contact";s:1:"1";s:19:"profile_affiliation";s:23:"University, Inc.";s:18:"profile_first_name";s:3:"Ben";s:22:"profile_street_address";s:19:"8718 Tot Ave. S.";s:12:"profile_city";s:6:"Mobile";s:13:"profile_state";s:2:"AL";s:15:"profile_country";s:3:"USA";s:15:"profile_zipcode";s:5:"36695";s:18:"profile_home_phone";s:10:"2599494420";s:17:"profile_last_name";s:6:"Powers";}';

    $fixed = preg_replace_callback(
        '/s:([0-9]+):"(.*?)";/',
        function ($matches) { return "s:".strlen($matches[2]).':"'.$matches[2].'";';     },
        $serialized
    );
    $original_array=unserialize($fixed);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($original_array);
```

You serailized string is corrupted so you need to repair it first then **unserialize**  it

**output**

```
    Array
    (
        [contact] => 1
        [profile_affiliation] => University, Inc.
        [profile_first_name] => Ben
        [profile_street_address] => 8718 Tot Ave. S.
        [profile_city] => Mobile
        [profile_state] => AL
        [profile_country] => USA
        [profile_zipcode] => 36695
        [profile_home_phone] => 2599494420
        [profile_last_name] => Powers
    )
```

Output:- https://eval.in/785908