# JSON, strange format, Wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to "parse" this string into something meaningful. Does anyone know what format this is? It comes from the MySQL Database of a Wordpress WooCommerce Plugin called "MVV WooCommerce Booking Addon". It somehow looks like JSON but it is not exactly.

```
a:6:
{
  s:8:"duration";s:1:"7";
  s:9:"timeStart";s:3:"600";
  s:7:"summary";s:29:"12. März 2020  10:00 - 17:00";
  s:9:"resources";a:0:{}
  s:5:"start";O:8:
  "DateTime":3:
  {
    s:4:"date";s:26:"2020-03-12 10:00:00.000000";
    s:13:"timezone_type";i:1;
    s:8:"timezone";s:6:"+00:00";
  }
  s:3:"end";O:8:
  "DateTime":3:
  {
    s:4:"date";s:26:"2020-03-12 17:00:00.000000";
    s:13:"timezone_type";i:1;
    s:8:"timezone";s:6:"+00:00";
  }
}
```

(There are no "\n"'s in the original string I tried to make it somehow a little bit more readable)

Thanks :)

Comment: This is a serialized object, which is basicaly a string that contains a byte-stream representation of an object in that case.

Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751303/how-can-i-parse-serialized-data-with-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse serialized data with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751303/how-can-i-parse-serialized-data-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a serialized object, try [unserialize](https://www.php.net/unserialize)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the solution :)